# Incompatiable Project VIsual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xna

So I have a project using XNA Framework to develop a 2D game. I went to work on it after working on it at my university and now whenever I open it I get this error

[image]

I have worked on it at uni before and never has this problem once I was home. I am currently running .NET Version 4.0 and XNA Version 4.0

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<XnaFrameworkVersion>v4.0</XnaFrameworkVersion>
<XnaPlatform>Windows</XnaPlatform>
```

So I see no reason why it should be saying it is incompatible. Is there any thing I can try?

Answer (score 0):

XNA is supported only in Visual Studio 2010. Its not supported in later VS versions.